# CS1950 The best overloaded add method Dictionary<string,Func<string>) for the collection initializer has some invalid arguments

Tags: c#

I am running into this error.. not sure what I am missing. This is reproducible code.

Sorry for the edit on the question- What if I wish to pass 2 strings to the function?

```
  class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        string myString = "test";
        string testString = "test";

        IDictionary<string, Func<string>> identityInformation = new Dictionary<string, Func<string>>
    {
        { "text1", () => {return test(myString, testString); } },
        { "text2", () => { return test(myString, testString); } }
    };

}
    public static string test(string myString, string testString)
    {
        return myString;
    }

}
```

Comment: `Dictionary<string, string>`

Comment: `{ "text1", test }`

Comment: Which of these you want depends on context you haven't provided (XY Problem); 1) `Dictionary<string, string>` 2) `Dictionary<string, Func<string, string>> .... {"text1", test}` 3) `{"text1", () => test(myString)}`

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
based on comments you can go with option A and call method when adding item into dictionary

```
string myString = "test";
string testString = "test";
var identityInformation = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "text1", test(myString, testString) },
    { "text2", test(myString, testString) }
};

public static string test(string myString, string testString)
{
    return myString;
}
```

---

Not sure which is defined interface you need to follow. There are multiple ways to fix it. Because Func  it has no parameters and returns string, which test method is not. Therefore:

A- Change dictionary to store results

```
 Dictionary<string, string>
```

B- change signature of dictionary to Func<string,string> and store delegates. Then myString as parameter will be used later.

```
IDictionary<string, Func<string,string>> identityInformation = new Dictionary<string, Func<string,string>>
{
    { "text1", test },
    { "text2", test }
};
```

C- add lambda

```
IDictionary<string, Func<string>> identityInformation = new Dictionary<string, Func<string>>
{
    { "text1", () => test(myString) },
    { "text2", () => test(myString) }
};
```

Comment: For the second approach how do I passs the myString parameter?

Comment: Updated the question- sorry for the confusion

Comment: @user3800888 Seeing your sample you still didnt answer how you want to use it. Do you want to result of Test method or you want to call Test method later on with some different parameters?

Comment: I want to store the result of the test method.

Comment: @user3800888 updated my answer

Comment: I am confused with the answer you provided.  If I want to store the result in the dictonary and call the function test with 2 string parameters, can you help me understand your point "mystring,teststring" parameter can be used later- later where? Can you elaborate or provide me an example where I can call a function with 2 arguments from this dictionary and store the result in this dictionary? BY just passing test, we aren't calling the function, right? Where do I call the function?

Comment: I have updated the code in the original question-- does that look good?